# Why is getElementsByName only usable from document in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyname

I would like to do something like this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var form_element_list = form.getElementsByName("foo");
```

But alas, it seems that `getElementsByName` can only be run from `document` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)).

**Question:**
why is it only possible to search from the document level? Especially as `name` attributes are mostly used in forms.

Thanks!

Comment: Because that's the way it is. That's how the API works. `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` are also methods of the `document` object.

Comment: Off-topic, but your first line should be `var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];`.

Comment: The first line is also invalid, it's `getElementsByTagName()`, and it returns also a HTML Collection. If you've to retrieve elements from a `form`, you can get the `form` with `id` and use the `name` like `form['name']`. Notice, that this will also return a HTMLCollection.

Comment: @Teemu is right http://jsfiddle.net/VZ87M/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is it only possible to search from the document level?

For historical reasons? We don't really know. However, names are global identifiers just as like as ids in `document.getElementsById`, only they are not unique.

> Especially as name attributes are mostly used in forms.

You would use the form's [`.elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements) for that purpose, it can be adressed with names as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use document.formName where (formName is the name attribute you gave the form) to get the form and document.formName.elements to get the elements in a collection. You can then reference the input elements by document.formName.elements.inputID

Comment: No. Use `document.forms.formName`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document):

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object. The Document interface **serves as an entry point to the web page's content** (the DOM tree, including elements such as  and ) and provides functionality global to the document (such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document)

As it serves as a entry point, the methods to look for the page's elements come from it.